# Partial fraction $\int \frac{dx}{2x^2 - 3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{dx}{2x^2 - 3}$$

I think I have to factor this but I don't know how to. If I don't know how to is it valid to do

$$\int \frac{dx}{2x^2 - 3} \quad =\quad \int \frac {Ax+ B}{2x^2 - 3}\,dx$$

Comment: We can factor the bottom using $2x^2 -3 = 2( x - \sqrt{3/2})(x + \sqrt{3/2})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{2x^2 - 3} = \int \frac{dx}{2(x^2 - 3/2)}\,dx = 1/2\int \frac{dx}{x^2 - 3}\,dx$$

We can factor the denominator by writing it as a difference of squares:

$$1/2 \int \left(\frac{A}{x+\sqrt{3/2}}+ \frac{B}{x-\sqrt{3/2}} \right)\,dx$$

Now we just need to determine the constants (numerators): $A, B$.

Comment: right to the point! +1